# Matching IDs and generating new columns

Tags: r

I am trying to match `sample_id1`, `sample_id2`, `value` from `File1.txt` with `sampleID` and `valueID` from `count.txt` and multiply count with `op1` and `op2`. I am not sure how I can do this in a `for` loop and define two new columns.

```
File1.txt
sample_id1   sample_id2    op1   op2  value
     IX12        IX78       2     3    15
     IX12        IX81       4     0    15   
     IX78        IX81       66    43   35
     IX12        IX78       23    10   35
     IX12        IX81       43    0    55
     IX12        IX78       43    0    55

File2.txt
sampleID  valueID  count    
   IX12      15   900
   IX12      35   2000
   IX12      55   3500
   IX78      15   865
   IX78      35   1500
   IX78      35   2400 
   IX81      15   234
   IX81      35   906
   IX81      55   2001


output.txt
sample_id1   sample_id2    op1   op2  value  new_col_op1  new_col_op2 
     IX12        IX78       2     3    15        1800       2595   
     IX12        IX81       4     0    15        3600         0
     IX78        IX81       66    43   35        99000      38958       
     ........
```

In `output.txt` I multiplied `op1` and `op2` from first row with 900 and 865 and generated `new_col_op1` and `new_col_op2`

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "match", what do you mean specifically? Inner join, left join, etc...? For example, are you trying to match each value of `sample_id1` to each value of `sampleID` and then do the sample for `sample_id2` and `sampleID`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to match each value of sample_id1 and value with sampleID and valueID and then performing operation on op1. Same method is applied to sample_id2

Comment: @hash  wonder how you got `2565` for the first row

Comment: sorry that was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this is what you wanted: (`df1` and `df2` are the datasets)

```
df11 <- transform( merge(df1[,-2], df2, by.x=c("sample_id1", "value"), by.y=c("sampleID", "valueID")),  new_col_op1=op1*count)
df12 <- transform( merge(df1[,-1], df2, by.x=c("sample_id2", "value"), by.y=c("sampleID", "valueID")),  new_col_op2=op2*count)

 res <- merge(df11, df12, by=c("value", "op1", "op2"),sort=FALSE)
  head(res,4)
 #  value op1 op2 sample_id1 count.x new_col_op1 sample_id2 count.y new_col_op2
 #1    15   2   3       IX12     900        1800       IX78     865        2595
 #2    15   4   0       IX12     900        3600       IX81     234           0
 #3    35  23  10       IX12    2000       46000       IX78    1500       15000
 #4    35  23  10       IX12    2000       46000       IX78    2400       24000
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df11 <-  inner_join(df1[,-2],setNames(df2, c("sample_id1", "value", "count"))) %>% mutate(new_col_op1=op1*count)
 df12 <-  inner_join(df1[,-1],setNames(df2, c("sample_id2", "value", "count"))) %>% mutate(new_col_op2=op2*count)
 res1 <- inner_join(df11, df12, by=c("op1", "op2", "value"))

  head(res1,4)
  #  sample_id1 op1 op2 value count.x new_col_op1 sample_id2 count.y new_col_op2
  #1       IX12   2   3    15     900        1800       IX78     865        2595
  #2       IX12   4   0    15     900        3600       IX81     234           0
  #3       IX12  23  10    35    2000       46000       IX78    1500       15000
  #4       IX12  23  10    35    2000       46000       IX78    2400       24000
```

Comment: merging df11 with df12 gives me following problem because I have a huge File1.txt *** caught segfault ***
address 0x2aacbf0f2000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: merge.data.frame(df11, df12, by = c("Percentage"), sort = FALSE)
 2: merge(df11, df12, by = c("value"), sort = FALSE)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace

Comment: @hash It is not clear how `huge` is your file.  You may try with `dplyr` or `data.table` but if the file is really very big, you may need some databases.  I will update with a `dplyr` solution.